# How to fetch directory with highest number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

How can I select directory with largest number

eg.

1. a/b/c/d.1/log/
2. a/b/c/d/logs/
3. a/b/c/d.3/logs/
4. a/b/c/d.2/logs/

Now I want to select only those logs under the directory which has been generated under a/b/c/d.3/logs as d.3 is greatest

Result or print = "a/b/c/d.3/logs/"

Comment: is the number always on the fourth position? what is the input (list, strings, other)
?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is a list of strings, and that you want to match the fourth directory level, you can use a regex to extract the number and `max` to get the max:

```
dirs = ['a/b/c/d.1/log/',
        'a/b/c/d/logs/',
        'a/b/c/d.3/logs/',
        'a/b/c/d.2/logs/',
        'a/b/c/d.11/logs/',
       ]

def get_int(s, pos=3):
    m = re.search(r'(?:.+?/){3}[^/\d]+(\d+)/', s)
    return int(m.group(1)) if m else -1

max(dirs, key=get_int)
```

output:

```
'a/b/c/d.11/logs/'
```